# Изменение одного div-а при наведении курсором на другой

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Собственно, такой и вопрос. Как сделать так чтобы при наведении на один див, менялся фон другого дива? Например

```
<div class="test">Наводим тут</div>

<div class="test2">Меняется этот</div>
```

Comment: не используйте классы как id

Comment: как классы как айди?

Comment: @RavenSeven - когда есть единственный элемент, надо делать id, а-то получится "Лягушка аквариумная Коля" - новый класс животных. Практический смысл по id  поиск быстрее

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto), может объясните, почему вы заминусовали ответ, который дал [[@Zhukov Roman](/users/10590/zhukov-roman)](/users/10590/zhukov-roman)? Вы считаете что там нет логики? Хотелось бы вашу версию услышать.

Теперь по вопросу ТС и принципиально используя **.hover()**:

```
$('.test').hover(
    function(){
        $('.test2').css('background-color','#FF0');
    },
    function(){
        $('.test2').css('background-color','#FFF');
    }
);
```

Comment: Да) Спасибо) То что нужно.

Comment: потому-что ТС выберет ответ с пояснением и кодом.

Comment: @Deonis, постараюсь догадаться: потому что ДУМАТЬ СЛОЖНО.

Answer (score 5):

[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: минус за то что это не ответ просто ссылка на документацию ответом не является

Comment: @eicto, для того, кто хочет разобраться в данном вопросе — данного ответа достаточно. А помогать тем, кто не хочет — нет желания.

Comment: На собеседовании вы тоже ссылками RTFM отвечать будете ?

Comment: @eicto ничего себе вы сравнили. Да и даже для мне является ответом данная ссылка, человеку который практически никогда не работал с js, а с jquery вообще никогда.

Comment: [RTFM](http://tonguc.wordpress.com/2006/12/27/how-to-answer-questions-the-smart-way/) #8 есть и другая причина - целостность информации, как вам если бы вики состояла из ссылок только ?

Comment: @eicto вот я не понимаю зачем Вы сравниваете теплое с мягким? Это форум, а не энциклопедия. Тем более в данном конкретном случае я бы понял ответ даже если бы написали просто .hover(), без ссылки

Comment: Это не совсем форум, это Q/A форум.

Answer (score 1):

Для соседних элементов:

```css
 .block1:hover ~ .block2 h1 { color: red;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class=block2><h1>нет</h1></div>
  <div class=block1>Проведите надо мной</div>
  <div class=block2><h1>да</h1></div>
  <hr>
  <div class=block2><h1>да</h1></div>
  <div>
    <div class=block2><h1>нет</h1></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=block2><h1>нет</h1></div>
```

А таким как жуков: -проходи мимо если помогать не хочешь, никто не заставляет тебя тратить энергию. Такие как ты только засоряют форумы. И таких примеров  миллион!

Comment: Для соседних `+`, а не `~`.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.test:hover + .test2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Наводим тут</div>
<div class="test2">Меняется этот</div>
```